# Вывести список файлов с сортировкой в Linux

Tags: linux

Какой командой bash в Linux (debian) можно вывести список файлов и папок конкретной директории, отсортированных по правам доступа (chmod)?

Comment: `ls -l |sort` чем-то не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ: ls -l |sort -k1 (сортировка по первому столбцу).